# convert pseudo code in algorithm2e style

Tags: algorithm2e

If I want to write

```
FOR each label, entities IN custom_entities:
        FOR each ent IN entities:
            span = create_span(doc, ent[1], ent[2], label)
            doc.ents = combine_entities(doc.ents, [span])
```

this portion of pseudo-code using **algorithm2e**, how could I write that?

Comment: The `algorithm2e` documentation lists the various predefined commands that you can use for "for-each" as well as several code examples that cover the things that you want to do for your pseudocode, and I recommend taking a look